# Java - TrayIcon messages not displaying on Windows XP, Vista

Tags: java, swing, popup, message, trayicon

I'm writing an application that utilizes Java's `TrayIcon` class, but I can't seem to get it to display messages on Windows XP/Vista. Is this a known issue or is there something that I'm missing? (Messages appear as they should on Windows 7)

Code:

```
public class SysTray {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TrayIcon icon = new TrayIcon(getImage());

        icon.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Good");
            }
        });
        SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(icon);

        icon.displayMessage("Attention", "Please click here", 
            TrayIcon.MessageType.WARNING);
    }

    private static Image getImage() throws HeadlessException {
        Icon defaultIcon = MetalIconFactory.getTreeHardDriveIcon();
        Image img = new BufferedImage(defaultIcon.getIconWidth(), 
            defaultIcon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        defaultIcon.paintIcon(new Panel(), img.getGraphics(), 0, 0);

        return img;
    }
}
```

Edit: computers were both using the latest version of Java

Edit II: 
Results of tests on various computers:

- Windows XP, J7_25 (1.7.0_25-b16): Works
- Windows 7, J7_25 (1.7.0_25-b17): Works
- Windows XP, J7_25 (1.7.0_25-b17): Does not work

Comment: no there isn't any issue with displayMessage() on WinXP/7/8 (never touched Vista) on > JDK_6.18

Comment: @mKorbel That's not (shouldn't be) an issue here - both computers are on a version > 6.18

Comment: sorry your comment isn't more clear than your question, btw just my curiosity, nothing else (otherwise I'd be ask for an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable and caused a.m. lack on WinXP) StringConstants are from C++/.Net invoked from JNI/A or is some hand_Made

Comment: @mKorbel `StringConstants` is just a hand made class with.. well. Strings that are constant

Comment: Show the simplest possible runnable code which _should_ do what you expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

see whats happened (Java6_022 and Java7_21, tested on both JDKs)

WinXP -            -> [image]

Win8 - -> [image]

from code

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.SystemTray;
import java.awt.TrayIcon;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalIconFactory;

public class SysTray {

    public SysTray() {
        TrayIcon icon = new TrayIcon(getImage());
        icon.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Good");
            }
        });
        try {
            SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(icon);
        } catch (AWTException ex) {
        }
        icon.displayMessage("Attn","Click here",TrayIcon.MessageType.WARNING);
    }

    private Image getImage() throws HeadlessException {
        Icon defaultIcon = MetalIconFactory.getTreeHardDriveIcon();
        Image img = new BufferedImage(defaultIcon.getIconWidth(),
                defaultIcon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        defaultIcon.paintIcon(new JPanel(), img.getGraphics(), 0, 0);
        return img;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SysTray sysTray = new SysTray();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry I haven't - `Windows XP, J7_25 (1.7.0_25-b17): Does not work`, [then search and to report](http://search.oracle.com/search/search?search_p_main_operator=all&start=1&group=bugs.sun.com&q=trayicon)

Comment: I instaled latest 1.7.0_25-b17 win32b, no issue, compiled in JDK1.6_022 and JDK1.7._011